Consuming StreamingResponseBody from react app
I am a newbie on react, so please bear with me.
I have a rest endpoint in springboot using StreamingResponseBody to emit data.
    @GetMapping("/3Dpoints")
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> getPoints() {

        StreamingResponseBody stream = out -> {
            service.getPoints(out);
        };
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .body(stream);

    }

service:getPoints is:
public void streamPointCloud(java.io.OutputStream out) throws Exception{
        String path= ....;
        File file = new File(path);
        PointReader reader = new PointReader (file);
        for (Point p : reader.getPoints()) {
            MyPoint mp = new MyPoint(p.getX(), p.getY(), p.getZ());
            out.write((mp.toString()+"\n").getBytes());
        }
    }

Rest endpoint streams the point data as strings.
Client is a react app, with consuming code as:
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    points: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch('/3Dpoints');
    const body = await response.text();
    this.setState({points: body});
  }

  render() {
    const {points} = this.state;
    return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <div className="App-intro">
              <h2>Points</h2>
              {points.map(point =>
                  <div>
                    {point.body}
                  </div>
              )}
            </div>
          </header>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;

When I launch react app, I can see rest endpoint being invoked.
But I don't see any data printed on react UI.
What mistake am I making in this whole flow?

In Typescript, doesn't the assignment of the state property (on line 6) shadow the state property on the parent?  Try logging the value of this.state in your render function, I'm guessing it's going to still have the default assignment of [].

If my understanding is right, I would recommend using constructor assignment to set the value of state, instead of shadowing.
constructor(props) { super(props) this.state = {porints: []}; }

Did you try useState instead of componentDidMount? Before component rendered, your point was empty, so map(point=> <div/>) can have error
